# How Many Android App Stores to Submit ...?

Tags: android, android-layout, samsung-mobile, amazon-appstore

Except Google's app store, there are Samsung app store, Amazon app store, etc...

As a developer, do I have to submit my app to all of the stores one by one?? Or once I submitted my app to Google, all of the other stores would find my app and publish it on their store automatically??

If I have to submit it one by one, anybody could give me the list of major stores?

As a Galaxy customer, is it better to download an app from Samsung's store instead of Google's store??  I am using iPhone for long time, I just feel a little bit confused...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two largest stores are going to being the Play Store (aka Android Market) and the Amazon App Store that is available to Kindle Fire users.  You need to submit your applications separately.  Your application needs to be of high quality to get into the Amazon App Store.

List of Android Application Stores

1. Play Store (Android Market)
2. Amazon App Store
3. Opera Mobile App Store
4. GetJar
5. AndAppStore
6. Handango
7. OnlyAndroid Superstore by Mobihand
8. Insyde Market
9. Appoke
10. SlideME
11. YAAM Market
12. Samsung App Store

Comment: Do I have to submit to Samsung, Motorola, etc. separately?? Any special requirements for them?? If I got a Samsung's phone, is it really better to download an app on Samsung's store??  Thanks. I am confused...

Comment: As I said in my answer you need to submit them separately.  I have a Samsung phone and I typically download from the Play Store (Android Market) only.  The Play Store (Android Market) has by far the largest number of downloads.

Comment: A lot of the private App Stores will have much stronger requirements for your app to be accepted in the store. This way they have higher quality apps in their respective stores.

Comment: What would be those stronger requirements?? Thanks!!

Comment: It is completely subject to the people reviewing the app.  It may be performance, aesthetics, size of target audience, etc...

Comment: I see, how about programmatic requirements?

Comment: You should be submitting .apks for each store so the programming requirements should be the same.

Comment: Should I submit the same APK which I submitted to Play Store and signed with same key?